# program crashes sometimes

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

The following routine is expected to remove the node at the start of a single linked list but it fails sometimes.

```
void remove_from_front(node *start)
{
    delete start;
    start = start->link;
    print_list(start);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are few problems I can see:

1. You are freeing the `start` node and then accessing the freed memory. This is incorrect, it leads to undefined behavior which means anything can happen. In one run it might work and in the next run it might crash.
2. Your function needs to make changes to the head of the list but it is not making the changes visible to the called function as it is not returning anything and the argument `start` is passed by value. To fix this either pass the address or reference of the `start` pointer.
3. Your function might be called on an empty list, `start = NULL`. You need to handle that case.

Correct implementation:

```
void remove_from_front(node **start) {

  // if list is empty..nothing to remove..return.
  if(*start == NULL) {
     return;
  }

  // save the address of the node following the start in new_start 
  node *new_start = (*start)->link;

  // now delete the start node.
  delete *start;

 // new_start is now the new start of the list.
 // And since start was passed by address, the change is reflected in the
 // calling function.
  *start = new_start;
}
```

Comment: You could always do a `node * temp = *start` to make the code more readable.

Comment: @Muggen: Yes you can do that too.

Answer (score 5):

Once you `delete start`, you can't safely use pieces of what `start` used to point to. That's like letting go of a kite string and expecting to be able to take hold of it again later-- it might work, it might not.

Answer (score -1):

You are deleting start, then trying to dereference it by getting its link member. That will crash because you've just deleted it. You probably want something like this:

```
node *temp = start;
start = start->link;
delete temp;
print_list(start);
```

Comment: the dereference to get link member is very very unlikely to crash it.  printing it is more so.